# SQL Query :: CASE Condition

Tags: sql

I have a query where a course (C1, C5, C9 ...etc) should display the account of users with status `DONE/NOT DONE/PENDING` as the result. Note that a course can be either `DONE/NOT DONE` or `PENDING`:

```
count(u.userid)   ll.law_name   ll.law_course   ll.law_lesson   ll.score   ll.status
 4                  Berlyin         C1            L1              6.05      Done
 8                  Berlyin         C1            L1              NULL     Not Done

 4                  Elance          C9            L6               3.4      Done
 7                  Elance          C9            L6              NULL     Not Done

 2                  Indix           C5            L12              5.5     Done
 3                  Indix           C10           L3              NULL    Not Done
```

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(u.userid)), ll.law_name, ll.law_course, ll.law_lesson, 
CASE WHEN ll.score >=0 THEN Done
     WHEN ll.score <0 THEN Not Done
     WHEN ll.score !=0 THEN pending END AS "status"
FROM 
users u JOIN law_courses ll ON u.id = ll.userid GROUP BY ll.law_lesson
```

Comment: Your when expressions overlap. The first two cover the whole universe of reals (but not `null`), so the third doesn't make sense. Please show example scores and explain the rules for status.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: I just want to display a lesson status for each course with a count of how many are done in one row and not done in one row and finally Pending in one row

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to put the `case` statement in the `group by`.  Your logic for the three groups doesn't make sense (or at least, the "pending" group doesn't exist).  But this might put you on the right track:

```
SELECT count(*), ll.law_name, ll.law_course, ll.law_lesson, 
       (CASE WHEN ll.score >= 0 THEN 'Done'
             WHEN ll.score < 0 THEN 'Not Done'
             ELSE 'Pending'
        END) as status
FROM users u JOIN
     law_courses ll
     ON u.id = ll.userid
GROUP BY ll.law_name, ll.law_course, ll.law_lesson, 
         (CASE WHEN ll.score >= 0 THEN 'Done'
               WHEN ll.score < 0 THEN 'Not Done'
               ELSE 'Pending'
          END);
```

Comment: :: Thank You very much..it worked for me..made little changes an tried